# Is there a way to pass a block to update_attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm using Rails 4.2.1.  My table has a height column.  Is there a way to make a height conversion on the params passed in by the user?  Something like:

```
class WhateverController < ApplicationController
  def update
    current_user.update_attributes(user_params) do |u|
      u.height = convert_height_from_feet_to_inches
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :height_feet, :height_inches, :weight)
    end

    def convert_height_from_feet_to_inches
      (user_params[:height_feet] * 12) + user_params[:height_inches]
    end

end
```

For some reason update_attributes is not processing the block I'm trying to pass it.  Not sure why you wouldn't be able to pass a block to update_attributes.

Comment: That looks like something that belongs in either a view helper or the model, not the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this in the model, not the controller. Using virtual attributes you can ensure that setting either `height_feet` or `height_inches` will update `height` with the correct value, and vice versa:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :height_feet, :height_inches

  def height_feet=(feet)
    @height_feet = feet.present? ? feet.to_i : feet
    assign_height_from_feet_inches!
  end

  def height_inches=(inches)
    @height_inches = inches.present? ? inches.to_i : inches
    assign_height_from_feet_inches!
  end

  def height=(inches)
    self.height_feet, self.height_inches = inches.divmod(12)
  end

  private
  def assign_height_from_feet_inches!
    self[:height] =
      if self.height_feet.nil? || self.height_inches.nil?
        nil
      else
        self.height_feet * 12 + self.height_inches
      end
  end
end
```

Now in the controller you can just do this, and the rest will happen automatically:

```
current_user.update_attributes(user_params)
```

This will cause the `height` attribute to be automatically calculated every time the record is saved.

Comment: So even though my params hash will not contain a height attribute when update_attributes is called it will do an assignment of the height attribute?

Comment: Right. Since `user_params` has `:height_feet` and `:height_inches` attributes, Rails will automatically call `User#height_feet=` and `User#height_inches=`, which we defined above. Those methods in turn call `assign_height_from_feet_inches!`, which sets the `height` attribute.

Comment: P.S. You'll have to decide how you want to handle `nil` values. With the code above, `height` will be set to `nil` if either `height_feet` or `height_inches` is set to `nil`. You could, however, easily make it so that it counts `nil` as `0` in its calculation. It's up to you what the right thing to do is in your use case.

Comment: Nice, is self[:height] the same as self.height?  Or should it be self.height for the assignment?  I'm assuming self[:height] is not the params hash as that would be very confusing.  Am I correct?

Comment: Not sure why I would need the `def height=(inches)` method.  I don't have height_feet or height_inches attributes in my table.  Outside of that, this is great.

Comment: If you delete the `height=` method you can replace `self[:height] =` with `self.height = `. If you don't delete the `height=` method, then calling `self.height = ` would cause an infinite loop (`height=` → `height_feet=` → `assign_height_from_feet_inches!` → `height=`). I used `self[:height] =` to avoid that; it's just a way to [set the attribute directly](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) without invoking a setter method like `height=`.

Comment: And yes, you can safely delete the `height=` method. I just included it for symmetry's sake.